# @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY) in hibernate does not generate relation( table) when deployed

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have the following in my code:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;
```

And, I noted when I have the `@GeneratedValue` it simply does not generate my MySql tables, yet without that annotation it generates the respective tables.

What are the key points I should be checking for ?

Answer (score 0):

This is very tricky,as you might believe that you have define all the properties of hibernate properly and with the addition of @GeneratedValue annotation resulting a SQL Gram-mer error. Yet, I was able to resolve this by exploring the hibernate properties more carefully. Specifically look for the below properties in the hibernate configuration.
property name="hibernateProperties">

```
            hibernate.dialect=${hibernate.dialect}
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

for the hibernate.dialect --> you should have org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
yet you might see, it also generates table for -> org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect in MySQL database, which push you to a conclusion that you have set the hibernate properties properly. 
If any of your metadata annotation produces a grammer error, I strongly suggest you to check the hibernate properties

Thanks